# Python 3 os.walk(path) doesn't work when path has special characters

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

I'm trying to scan all directories inside a folder that has two special characters in it. The code is below.

```
import os
__loc__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),os.path.dirname(__file__))
path = os.path.join(__loc__,'Ração')
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
   for dir in dirs:
     print(dir)
```

But nothing appears...

Does anybody know an easy solution to accept special characters in

os.walk argument?

---

Edit: I don't get an error from the code. It just do not iterate.

Comment: Did you print the `path` to make sure it was what it should be?  `getcwd()` often returns unexpected results.

Comment: Yes, I printed. It is ok, it works without special characters like "ç"

Comment: Well when I tried it with the exact directory name that you used in the question, it worked for me.  You'll need to try harder to make a reproducible sample.